# ANGULAR ERROR TS2339

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: Iniciando el serve]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ERROR in
>   src/app/ADMINISTRADOR/subsistema/subsistema.component.html:21:99 -
>   error TS2339: Property 'p' does not exist on type
>   'SubsitemaComponent'.
>
> 21         
>                                                                                                        ~
>
> src/app/ADMINISTRADOR/subsistema/subsistema.component.ts:13:16
>       13   templateUrl: './subsistema.component.html',
>                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       Error occurs in the template of component SubsitemaComponent. src/app/ADMINISTRADOR/subsistema/subsistema.component.html:36:47 -
>   error TS2339: Property 'p' does not exist on type
>   'SubsitemaComponent'.
>
> 36         
>                                                    ~~~~~~
>
> src/app/ADMINISTRADOR/subsistema/subsistema.component.ts:13:16
>       13   templateUrl: './subsistema.component.html',
>                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       Error occurs in the template of component SubsitemaComponent.

Comment: Agrega el código que esta relacionado al error, no una imagen de la terminal ya que no dice mucho

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera listo amigo

Comment: Linea 21 de tu archivo `HTML`, en el error lo dice... estas usando una variable *p* que no existe. No será *e*?